# Which of these two is correct and what's the difference?

Tags: grammar, verbs

> Not **being** informed about the flight cancellation, we turned up at the airport only to find that we had to return the same time the following day.

or

> Not **having been** informed about the flight cancellation, we turned up at the airport only to find that we had to return the same time the following day.

Comment: To be informed of something by someone. To have been informed of something by someone. I was informed of the cancellation by my friend. I have been informed of cancellations in the past by the friends. Passive tense, present; passive tense, present perfect. There is also: Not informed of the cancellation, simple past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are both grammatically correct, but can mean two slightly different things.

> not being informed about the cancellation

has the feeling you did not know about the cancellation, your state of not knowing.

> not having been informed about the cancellation

has the feeling that someone ***should have*** told you about the flight cancellation but they did not.

However, it is possible that additional context could make the equivalent.

> An outage in the Skyscanner service left me *not being informed about the cancellation.*
>
> Not having been informed *(by the airlines)* left me not being informed